# Algebraic simultaneous equations using symbolic toolbox in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to use the symbolic toolbox of MATLAB to solve the following systems of equations. Given the following three equations

```
w+x+y+z==k1;
(w^2)+(x^2)+(y^2)+(z^2)==k2;
w*x*y*z==k3;
```

where `k1`, `k2`, and `k3` are constants and `w`, `x`, `y`, and `z` are variables. The objective is to obtain `p` and `q` in terms of each other only where

```
p==w+z;
q==(w*z)-(x*y);
```

That is, `w`, `x`, `y`, `z` should get eliminated in the `p` and `q` equations to get a single function, f(p,q,k1,k2,k3).

I am using the code in the following manner:

```
syms w x y z p q
eqn1 = w+x+y+z==k1;
eqn2 = w*x*y*z==k2;
eqn3 = (w^2)+(x^2)+(y^2)+(z^2)==k3;
eqn4 = w+z-p==0;
eqn5 = (w*z)-(x*y)-q==0;
solve(eqn1,eqn2,eqn3,eqn4,eqn5)
```

but the output is for `w`, `x`, etc. instead of one equation (in terms of variables `p` and `q` and the constants `k1`, `k2`, and `k3`). How to achieve this single function equation?

Comment: Does `solve(eqn1,eqn2,eqn3,eq4,eqn5,p,q)` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to extract a function, that will get p and give q.

assuming that we have (k1,k2,k3,p) and then we want q.

So equations are:

[k1,k2,k3,p]=f(w,x,y,z);

We want to inverse the f function. Meaning that we have [k1,k2,k3,p] and we want [x,y,z,w](4 equation and 4 unknown variable). Then we can calculate q by using [x,y,z,w].

use the following code. Remember that there is not a single answer. Equation has 2 answer.

```
    clc
    clear all

    syms w x y z p q k1 k2 k3
    eqn1 = w+x+y+z-k1;
    eqn2 = w*x*y*z-k2;
    eqn3 = (w^2)+(x^2)+(y^2)+(z^2)-k3;
    eqn4 = w+z-p;

    s=solve(eqn1,eqn2,eqn3,eqn4);
    x=s.x;
    y=s.y;
    z=s.z;
    w=s.w;

    q=(w.*z)-(x.*y); 

    %Removing repeated answers
    i=1;
    while i<=length(q)
        v=(simplify(q(i)-q)==0)&(1:length(q)~=i).';
        if any(v)
            q(v)=[];
            i=1;
        else
            i=i+1;
        end
    end
    %Displaying unique answers
    for i=1:length(q)
        fprintf('Answer %d\nq=%s\n\n',i,char(q(i)));
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Running your code

```
syms w x y z p q k1 k2 k3
eqn1 = w+x+y+z==k1;
eqn2 = w*x*y*z==k2;
eqn3 = (w^2)+(x^2)+(y^2)+(z^2)==k3;
eqn4 = w+z-p==0;
eqn5 = (w*z)-(x*y)-q==0;
S=solve(eqn1,eqn2,eqn3,eqn4,eqn5)
```

returns (on R2015a at least)

```
S = 
    q: [8x1 sym]
    w: [8x1 sym]
    x: [8x1 sym]
    y: [8x1 sym]
    z: [8x1 sym]
```

and each of these has 8 fields (corresponding to 8 solutions), and `S.q` is a function of `k1`, `k2`, `k3` and `p` only, so you have `q=f(k1,k2,k3,p)`. You can easily see that `q` is only dependent on these variables by using `symvar(S.q)`, which returns `[ k1, k2, k3, p]`. This is what you want, you could always do `f=S.q-q` to get something like `f(k1,k2,k3,p,q)=0`.

Basically, it turns out that the solution for `q` is not in terms of `w`, `x`, `y` or `z`, so you don't have to worry about those parts of the solution `S`. You can force this to happen by doing `S=solve(eqn1,eqn2,eqn3,eqn4,eqn5,w,x,y,z,q)` which will write all those variables in terms of `k1`, `k2`, `k3`, and `p`.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow, q was not showing up. Just one query - if we have to simplify the exression for q by substituting k1=1, k2=2, k3=3, how to do it?

Comment: Either define them at the start to be 1, 2 and 3, or use `subs(S.q,{k1 k2 k3},{1 2 3})` is you only want to substitute one set of `k` values, or `sq=matlabFunction(S.q);sq(1,2,3,p)` if you want to substitute lots of different `k`'s and `p`'s.